# Creating a modal panel with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, simplemodal

I want to popup a panel (like a popup window without the title bar or resize) where the background is darkened.  If you click on the darkened background the panel is closed.

Is there some good simple library for doing this like jQuery UI's dialog?  I would love to use jQuery UI, but their modal dialog windows have a title bar with close button I can't easily remove.

Ideally the panel popups up next to the mouse cursor (appropriately moving if too close to the browser's border).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also remove the JQuery UI's dialog title bar (or only the close button) with a few of CSS:

```
/* Create dialogs without close button */
.ui-dialog-no-close-button .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    display: none;
}

/* Create dialogs without title bar */
.ui-dialog-no-titlebar .ui-dialog-titlebar {
    display: none;
}
```

Then add it to the dialogClass property:

```
$("#dialogdiv").dialog({
    ...
    dialogClass: "ui-dialog-no-close-button",
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal)?

There are a few [demos](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/) that you can download to use as a base or for learning. You can also [download](http://code.google.com/p/simplemodal/downloads/list) the library directly on Google code.

All you need to do is include the JS file, set some default styles (CSS or as options) and away you go:

```
$('#some-element').modal();
```

You can include your options as follows:

```
$('#some-element').modal({options});
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like the [overlay dialog](http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/index.html) from JQuery Tools. It has an option for a mask behind the dialog box, demoed [here](http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/index.htm).

Comment: looks nice, I'll check it out.  Thanks.